# How can I provide summary XML Code documentation within the XAML Editor?

Tags: wpf, visual-studio, xaml, editor, design-time

I have created a set of converter classes (`IValueConverter`) which can be used in XAML code of WPF application. All classes are documented fully with XML code documentations: summary of the class and its both convert methods including the parameters.

Now I wonder why the Visual Studio XAML Editor does not show any of my documentations.
How can I provide documentation with IntelliSense when a developer uses the `Converter` resource types the `ConverterParameter`?

It would be useful when IntelliSence shows my comments when typing `ConverterParameter=`.
Is this possible? What do I have to do?

Conveter classes only a one example where I would like to provide documentation. For custom user controls I would like to do the same.

I uses Visual Studio 2015 and Visual Studio 2017.